# How can I delete/not display the nulls?

Tags: java

So my question is how can i Delete/not display the nulls,the excess not founds,and 0's when I run the program, also the last two attributes of the Student201 when 'runned', it displays in reverse order meaning the the nulls or the excess not founds or zeroes are displayed first.

also how can I add students 'predefined'

[This is my preferred output or display as much as possible w/o the not found](http://i761.photobucket.com/albums/xx256/tlb_05_09/12312412_1.png)

[This is not what I want, the not founds are printed first before the desired output](http://i761.photobucket.com/albums/xx256/tlb_05_09/321321_1.png)

Main.java

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Student a1=new Student();
        //a1.choosy();

        Student201 a2 =new Student201();
        a2.studinfo();
        a2.findstud("2000000001);
    }

}
```

Student201.java

```
public class Student201 {

    Student [] studarray = new Student[13];
    int x;
    public void studinfo()
    {



        for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) {

            studarray[x]= new Student();

        }


        Student estudyante1 = new Student();
        Student estudyante2 = new Student ();
        Student estudyante3 = new Student ();
        Student estudyante4 = new Student ();
        Student estudyante5 = new Student ();

        estudyante1.getStudName("Yves Francisco");
        estudyante1.getStudNum(2000000001);
        estudyante1.getYrLvl(5);
        estudyante1.getKors("CpE");
        estudyante1.getGender("Male");

        estudyante2.getStudName("Lance Eco");
        estudyante2.getStudNum(2000000002);
        estudyante2.getYrLvl(5);
        estudyante2.getKors("CpE");
        estudyante2.getGender("Male");

        estudyante3.getStudName("Karlos Castillo");
        estudyante3.getStudNum(2000000003);
        estudyante3.getYrLvl(5);
        estudyante3.getKors("CpE");
        estudyante3.getGender("Male");

        estudyante4.getStudName("Glenn Bordonada");
        estudyante4.getStudNum(2000000004);
        estudyante4.getYrLvl(4);
        estudyante4.getKors("ECE");
        estudyante4.getGender("Male");

        estudyante5.getStudName("Tim Tolentino");
        estudyante5.getStudNum(2000000005);
        estudyante5.getYrLvl(4);
        estudyante5.getKors("ECE");
        estudyante5.getGender("Male");

        studarray[0]=estudyante1;
        studarray[1]=estudyante2;
        studarray[2]=estudyante3;
        studarray[3]=estudyante4;
        studarray[4]=estudyante5;


    }
    public void findstud (String query) //String query for searching 

    {

    int ercatch=0;

    try{

         ercatch=Integer.parseInt(query);
       }

        catch (NumberFormatException m)
       {


       }

    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) 
    {

        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].setStudName())) //query.equalsIgnorecase for case sensitive inputs
        {
            System.out.println(studarray[x].setStudName()+"\n"+studarray[x].setStudNum()+"\n"+studarray[x].setYrLvl()+"\n"+studarray[x].setKors()+"\n"+studarray[x].setGender()+"\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }




    }

    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) 
    {
        if (ercatch == studarray[x].setStudNum()) //Integer.parseInt for int data types
        { 

            System.out.println(studarray[x].setStudName()+"\n"+studarray[x].setStudNum()+"\n"+studarray[x].setYrLvl()+"\n"+studarray[x].setKors()+"\n"+studarray[x].setGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        else if (ercatch != studarray[x].setStudNum()) 
        {

            System.out.println("Not Found!");
        }


    }

    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) 
    {

        if (ercatch == studarray[x].setYrLvl()) 
        {
            System.out.println(studarray[x].setStudName()+"\n"+studarray[x].setStudNum()+"\n"+studarray[x].setYrLvl()+"\n"+studarray[x].setKors()+"\n"+studarray[x].setGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        else if (ercatch != studarray[x].setYrLvl())
        {
            System.out.println("Not Found!");
        }

    }

    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++)
    {

        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].setKors())) 
        {

            System.out.println(studarray[x].setStudName()+"\n"+studarray[x].setStudNum()+"\n"+studarray[x].setYrLvl()+"\n"+studarray[x].setKors()+"\n"+studarray[x].setGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }


    }

    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) 
    {
        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].setGender())) 
        {

            System.out.println(studarray[x].setStudName()+"\n"+studarray[x].setStudNum()+"\n"+studarray[x].setYrLvl()+"\n"+studarray[x].setKors()+"\n"+studarray[x].setGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }


    }



 }

    public void addstud (String query) 

    {


    }

}
```

Student.Java

```
public class Student {


    private String StudName;
    private int StudNum;
    private int YrLvl;
    private String Kors;
    private String Gender;

    //this just for naming convention for the get and set
    public void getStudName (String name) {

        this.StudName=name;
    }


    public String setStudName() {

        return StudName;
    }

    public void getStudNum (int numero) {

        this.StudNum=numero;
    }

    public int setStudNum() {

        return StudNum;
    }

    public void getYrLvl (int yrlvl) {

        this.YrLvl=yrlvl;
    }

    public int setYrLvl()
    {
        return YrLvl;
    }

    public void getKors (String korse) {

        this.Kors=korse;
    }

    public String setKors() {

        return Kors;
    }

    public void getGender (String sex)
    {
        this.Gender=sex;
    }

    public String setGender() {

        return Gender;
    }

    public void choosy() {

        System.out.println("Here is the list and the information of the Students \n");


    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/

}
```

Comment: You've mixed up getters and setters by the way : the `getX` should accept no parameter and return the field's value while the `setX` should accept a single parameter and set the field to that value.

Comment: thanks buddy, I know its a liitle mixed up , i name set to  get and get to set, but its all naming convention anyway, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i Delete/not display the nulls,the excess not founds,and 0's

First, remove this

```
    for (x=0;x<studarray.length;x++) {
        studarray[x]= new Student();
    }
```

Then, all the students are null except for those you defined, which you can explicitly ignore them.

```
for (int x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {
    Student s = studarray[x];
    if (s == null) {
        continue; // here
    }

    // Check all your fields in a single loop
    if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getStudName())) {

    } else if (Integer.parseInt(query) == s.getStudNum()) {

    } else {
        System.out.println("Student not found using query " + query);
    }
}
```

Comment: man it worked THANKS!, so that for loop at the start causes it, can you enlighten me pls? also one more thing when I choose to find using the stud number or the yr lvl at let say a2.findstud("4"); this shows:

This is the only record
This is the only record
This is the only record
Glenn Bordonada
2000000004
4
ECE
Male

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you have totally mixed up **getters** and **setters**, **getters** should return the value without any parameter, and **setters** set the field to a vala ue with parameter, like this

```
public void setStudName (String name) {
    this.StudName=name;
}

public String getStudName() {
    return StudName;
}

public void setStudNum (int numero) {
    this.StudNum=numero;
}

public int getStudNum() {
    return StudNum;
}
```

Since you don't want to display the Not found result, so I remove it and this is your `Student201` class.

```
public class Student201 {

Student[] studarray = new Student[13];
int x;

public void studinfo() {

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {

        studarray[x] = new Student();

    }

    Student estudyante1 = new Student();
    Student estudyante2 = new Student();
    Student estudyante3 = new Student();
    Student estudyante4 = new Student();
    Student estudyante5 = new Student();

    estudyante1.setStudName("Yves Francisco");
    estudyante1.setStudNum(2000000001);
    estudyante1.setYrLvl(5);
    estudyante1.setKors("CpE");
    estudyante1.setGender("Male");

    estudyante2.setStudName("Lance Eco");
    estudyante2.setStudNum(2000000002);
    estudyante2.setYrLvl(5);
    estudyante2.setKors("CpE");
    estudyante2.setGender("Male");

    estudyante3.setStudName("Karlos Castillo");
    estudyante3.setStudNum(2000000003);
    estudyante3.setYrLvl(5);
    estudyante3.setKors("CpE");
    estudyante3.setGender("Male");

    estudyante4.setStudName("Glenn Bordonada");
    estudyante4.setStudNum(2000000004);
    estudyante4.setYrLvl(4);
    estudyante4.setKors("ECE");
    estudyante4.setGender("Male");

    estudyante5.setStudName("Tim Tolentino");
    estudyante5.setStudNum(2000000005);
    estudyante5.setYrLvl(4);
    estudyante5.setKors("ECE");
    estudyante5.setGender("Male");

    studarray[0] = estudyante1;
    studarray[1] = estudyante2;
    studarray[2] = estudyante3;
    studarray[3] = estudyante4;
    studarray[4] = estudyante5;

}

public void findstud(String query) //String query for searching 
{

    int ercatch = 0;

    try {
        ercatch = Integer.parseInt(query);
    } catch (NumberFormatException m) {
    }

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {

        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].getStudName())) //query.equalsIgnorecase for case sensitive inputs
        {
            System.out.println(studarray[x].getStudName() + "\n" + studarray[x].getStudNum() + "\n" + studarray[x].getYrLvl() + "\n" + studarray[x].getKors() + "\n" + studarray[x].getGender() + "\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {
        if (ercatch == studarray[x].getStudNum()) //Integer.parseInt for int data types
        {

            System.out.println(studarray[x].getStudName() + "\n" + studarray[x].getStudNum() + "\n" + studarray[x].getYrLvl() + "\n" + studarray[x].getKors() + "\n" + studarray[x].getGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {

        if (ercatch == studarray[x].getYrLvl()) {
            System.out.println(studarray[x].getStudName() + "\n" + studarray[x].getStudNum() + "\n" + studarray[x].getYrLvl() + "\n" + studarray[x].getKors() + "\n" + studarray[x].getGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {

        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].getKors())) {

            System.out.println(studarray[x].getStudName() + "\n" + studarray[x].getStudNum() + "\n" + studarray[x].getYrLvl() + "\n" + studarray[x].getKors() + "\n" + studarray[x].getGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    for (x = 0; x < studarray.length; x++) {
        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(studarray[x].getGender())) {

            System.out.println(studarray[x].getStudName() + "\n" + studarray[x].getStudNum() + "\n" + studarray[x].getYrLvl() + "\n" + studarray[x].getKors() + "\n" + studarray[x].getGender());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }
}

public void addstud(String query) {

}
```

}

Comment: You can move each of those if statements into a single for loop over the array and convert them to OR conditions

Comment: @RogerT thanks bud, but if I remove the else if in that loop, what if the user searched like a2.findstud("2000000009"), and that 200000009 is not in my predefined data, thats why I have put that else if in that area :), Im just confused why the output sometimes displays the 0's and nulls' and not founds before the actual output of the program, sometimes the actual output is displayed at the end. was it because of the arrays or the memory?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks bud, but how can i implement that, it might ruin the whole process??

Comment: @YvesFrancisco Do you actually want to do the exact same loop to check individually for every single field? In "runtime" terms, then for M fields and N students, you are running M * N total calculations, making the solution less than optimal. You can have a single for loop over the array, then put your each of your if statements within that loop... Nothing is ruined

Comment: @cricket_007 ok ill try it later and come back if it worked out, thanks bud! also ill try the OR conditions